# Seeking resources to help formulate expressions in mathematical notation, and to think like a mathematician

Tags: reference-request, notation

I have huge gaps in my mathematical knowledge, mainly because I'm an engineer and the math we study is very limited.

Now I'm into Deep Learning research. Most of the time I have a problem formulating things mathematically. I want a suggestion for a book or any kind of resource that will help me formulate expressions, algorithms, etc, mathematically.

Also, I want to think like a mathematician, any recommendation about this matter?

Comment: I advise you the recent book of Gilbert STRANG : "Linear algebra and learning from data" Wellesley-Cambridge Ed. 2019 : it is wonderfully clear (G. Strang is a MIT professor)

Comment: I recommend a looking at a discrete math textbook. Modern ones will typically contain algorithms and since they study finite sets you can appeal to intuition continuously as you digest the mathematical definitions and notation. Also, in practice, finite structures are ubiquitous so it would serve your applied interests as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions